# Map of maps to a single map by aggregating keys

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a structure like this one:

```
Map<KeyType1, Map<KeyType2, List<ValueType>>>
```

And also a class holding both **KeyType1** and **KeyType2**, let's call it **AggregatedKey**. It can be instantiated using its constructor:

```
public AggregatedKey(KeyType1 keyType1, KeyType2 keyType2)
```

My goal is to map the structure above to something like:

```
Map<AggregatedKey, List<ValueType>>
```

So, basically, the keys should be mapped to a single aggregated key.

How can I achieve that using Java 9?

Comment: Do you have a function that builds aggregated key from given two keys?

Comment: They can be aggregated by using the constructor: AggregatedKey(KeyType1, KeyType2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the trick

```
Map<KeyType1, Map<KeyType2, List<String>>> m = new HashMap<>();
Map<AggregatedKey, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
m.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
    entry.getValue().entrySet().forEach(nestedEntry -> {
        result.put(new AggregatedKey(entry.getKey(), nestedEntry.getKey()), nestedEntry.getValue());
    });
});
```

Don't forget to implement `hashcode/equals` in your `AggregatedKey`, otherwise you'll have some trouble using the `result` map.

Comment: I marked this as accepted as I find it the shortest, even though personally I don't like having to create an external aggregator (like the result here), it is easier to understand.

Comment: @Anakin001 Actually, this is a bit another version of `for...each`. In case you use a stream, you should retrieve a result instead of updating the created collection.

Comment: You are right! It's fine as it is though, it's clear and it works (I just tested it).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like so using streams.

- first stream the entry set of the outer map
- then invoke `flatMap` to stream the inner map's `entrySet`
- create the `AggregatedKey` instance using `outerEntry.getKey()` and `innerEntry.getKey()` Note this requires that class to have a constructor accepting the keys.
- then put that instance and the value from the inner map (`List<ValueType>`) in an `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` instance to pass to the collector.
- create the new map with the key and value of the `SimpleEntry`

Given the following source map.

```
Map<KeyType1, Map<KeyType2, List<ValueType>>> map =
        new HashMap<>();  // contains the info to be remapped.
```

Here is the result

```
Map<AggregatedKey, List<ValueType>> result = map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(outerEntry-> outerEntry
                        .getValue().entrySet().stream()
                        .map(innerEntry -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(
                new AggregatedKey(outerEntry.getKey(),innerEntry.getKey()),
                                innerEntry.getValue())))
        
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey,
                AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue));

    }
```

Comment: This is the most 'beautiful' answer as it just applies stream operations and gets de result, it's too bad Stackoverflow only lets me choose one accepted answer :(

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the ways:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, String> innerMap1 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, String> innerMap2 = new HashMap<>();
    innerMap1.put("k11", "v11");
    innerMap1.put("k12", "v12");
    innerMap1.put("k13", "v13");
    innerMap2.put("k21", "v22");
    innerMap2.put("k22", "v22");
    map.put("k1", innerMap1);
    map.put("k2", innerMap2);
    Map<String, String> result = map
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(stringMapEntry ->
                stringMapEntry
                        .getValue()
                        .entrySet()
                        .stream()
                            .map(stringStringEntry ->
                                    new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String>(
                                            buildAggregatedKey(
                                                    stringMapEntry.getKey(), 
                                                    stringStringEntry.getKey()
                                            ), 
                                            stringStringEntry.getValue()
                                    )
                            )
            ).collect(Collectors.toMap(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey, AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue));
    System.out.println(result);
}

private static String buildAggregatedKey(String key1, String key2){
   return  key1 + "_" + key2;
}
```

Where you change this `buildAggregatedKey` to meet your aggregation logic.

Answer (score 1):

```java
public static final class AggregatedKey<K1, K2> {

    private final K1 one;
    private final K2 two;

    public AggregatedKey(K1 one, K2 two) {
        this.one = one;
        this.two = two;
    }
}

public static <K1, K2, V> Map<AggregatedKey<K1, K2>, List<V>> convert1(Map<K1, Map<K2, List<V>>> map) {
    Map<AggregatedKey<K1, K2>, List<V>> res = new HashMap<>();

    for (Map.Entry<K1, Map<K2, List<V>>> one : map.entrySet())
        for (Map.Entry<K2, List<V>> two : one.getValue().entrySet())
            res.put(new AggregatedKey<>(one.getKey(), two.getKey()), two.getValue());

    return res;
}

public static <K1, K2, V> Map<AggregatedKey<K1, K2>, List<V>> convert2(Map<K1, Map<K2, List<V>>> map) {
    return map.entrySet().stream()
            .flatMap(e1 -> e1.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                    .map(e2 -> new AggregatedKey<>(new AggregatedKey<>(e1.getKey(), e2.getKey()), e2.getValue())))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(tuple -> tuple.one, tuple -> tuple.two));
}
```

Comment: It's funny how lately I tend to think in terms of streams even though sometimes the classic for can do a better job. This is by far the easiest solution to understand in my opinion, but I marked Pilpo's answer as accepted as I wanted a streams solution in this case.

Comment: @Anakin001 see my updated answer. But I think that `converter1()` is simplier.

Comment: @Anakin001 *but I marked Pilpo's answer as accepted as I wanted a streams solution in this case.*  Then why did you accept the other answer?  There were no streams involved.

Comment: @WJS indeed, it was a mistake, I wanted to say 'functional programming' and I ended up saying 'streams' (technically, it was a reading mistake in the first place, I didn't see that the solution calls 'forEach' without streaming the entry set first, but nonetheless, what I really wanted was to have a more 'functional' solution).

Answer (score 1):

this is a sample test using streams where in the first step it transforms the inner element of the map and in the second it collects to a Map:

```
package prove.aggregatemap;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class TestAggregator {

@Test
public void aggregate() {
    Map<String, List<String>> letter_map= Map.of("first", List.of("one","two","three"),
            "second", List.of("four","five","six"),
            "third", List.of("seven","eight","nine"));
    Map<String, List<String>> num_map= Map.of("first_num", List.of("1","2","3"), "second_num", List.of("4","5","6"), "third_num", List.of("7","8","9"));
    Map<String,Map<String,List<String>>> mapOfMaps=Map.of("letter",letter_map,"num",num_map);

    Map<AggregateKey, List<String>> result=mapOfMaps.entrySet().stream().flatMap(entry ->
       entry.getValue().entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                inner_entry -> new AggregateKey(entry.getKey(), inner_entry.getKey()),
                inner_entry -> inner_entry.getValue())).entrySet().stream()
    ).collect(Collectors.toMap(entry->entry.getKey(),entry->entry.getValue()));
    Assert.assertEquals(List.of("one","two","three"),result.get(new AggregateKey("letter","first")));
    Assert.assertEquals(List.of("four","five","six"),result.get(new AggregateKey("letter","second")));
    Assert.assertEquals(List.of("seven","eight","nine"),result.get(new AggregateKey("letter","third")));
}
```

}